# Isolate section of SVG when mouse is hovered

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am attempting to build an interactive map from scratch. I have an SVG of the map of Canada that has separate layers for each province. I'd like to highlight a specific province/territory when the mouse is hovered over it.

I have tried using a function that gets the live update of the mouse coordinates, but I am unsure as to how to figure out which section of the image it is on. I am unsure as to if this is the best method of doing it.

Through some of my research, I have found a method of gathering the pointer coordinates:

```
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

function showCoords() {
  x = event.clientX;
  y = event.clientY;
}
```

And I call it around the SVG using:

```
<div onmousemove="showCoords()">
   ...SVG HERE
</div>
```

I can select the different layers inside of the SVG, but the question is if I can find a way of checking which layer my mouse is currently over.

Thank you!

---

Edit:
I have reached a solution that accomplishes my goal, but I am unsure as to if it is efficient.

Using CSS, I fill each group upon hover:

```
#canada { 
    fill: hsl(0, 0%, 29%);
}
#canada g {
    transition: .3s;
}
#canada g:hover { 
    fill: hsl(189, 88%, 59%);
}
```

I am also using the onClick option on each group to pull up their dialogue.

Comment: Can you post some code which demonstrates what you've tried to do?

Comment: @Josh I have updated the post above with some smaller amounts of code. If the SVG is needed, it can be found here: https://pastebin.com/2JGxQ93U

Comment: If you can do a hover, then you can set up onmouseover/onmouseout event handlers for each of the items. They pretty much all have ids, which makes them easy to deal with. Should be quite efficient. Notes on event handlers - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459890/javascript-function-doesnt-work-when-link-is-clicked/43459991#43459991

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? Just keep "data-name" attribute on each `<g>` inside svg code.

```js
let x = 0;
let y = 0;

let svgCountry = document.querySelector("#states svg");
let svgStates = svgCountry.querySelectorAll("[data-name]");
let resContainer = document.getElementById("state-hovered-is");

// init tooltip
function showCoords(event) {
  let x = event.clientX;
  let y = event.clientY;
  resContainer.setAttribute("style", "left:" + (x + 15) + "px;" + "top:" + (y - 50) + "px;");
}
// close tooltip
function clearCoor() {
  resContainer.innerHTML = "";
}

// clear everything
function clearAllOn() {
  svgStates.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove("hover");
    resContainer.innerHTML = "";
    console.clear();
  });
}

// display current state in div
function displayState(el) {
  var res = el.getAttribute("data-name");
  el.classList.add("hover");
  resContainer.innerHTML = "<p>You're at" + " " + res + "</p>";
  console.log(res);
}


svgStates.forEach(function(el) {
  // mouse events
  el.addEventListener("mouseenter", function() {
    displayState(el);
  });
  el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function() {
    clearAllOn();
  });
  // touch events
  el.addEventListener("touchstart", function() {
    clearAllOn();
    displayState(el);
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

g.hover {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#states {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

#state-hovered-is {
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.76);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#state-hovered-is p {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div id="states" onmousemove="showCoords(event)" onmouseout="clearCoor()">
<!-- State name here -->
<div id="state-hovered-is"></div>
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 961.38 830.7">
    <defs>
      <style>
        .cls-1 { fill: #fff;}
        .cls-2 {fill: #b8c4e6;}
        .cls-3 {fill: #ce8080;}
        .cls-4 {fill: #e99bd2;}
        .cls-5 {fill: #acac90;}
        .cls-6 {fill: #e6c0c0;}
        .cls-7 {fill: #4d6ac1;}
        .cls-8 {fill: #c9e6b8;}
        .cls-9 {fill: #f3f3db;}
        .cls-10 {fill: #cece71;}
        .cls-11 {fill: #7188ce;}
        .cls-12 {fill: #daa0a0;}
        .cls-13 {fill: #91916b;}
        .cls-14 {fill: #dada94;}
        .cls-15 {fill: #916b86;}
      </style>
    </defs>
    <title>Canada</title>
    <g id="Layer_1">
      <ellipse class="cls-1" cx="480.69" cy="415.35" rx="679.8" ry="587.39" />
      <path class="cls-1" d="M539.84,220.75c-2.45,5-6.57,8.18-10.72,11.7l2-9.56C534.53,224.17,537,221.84,539.84,220.75Z" transform="translate(-0.06 -0.26)" />
      <path class="cls-1" d="M53,543.56c-1.09,2.13-2.18,4.23-3.52,6.84l-.51-10.68.56-.25Z" transform="translate(-0.06 -0.26)" />
      <path class="cls-1" d="M771.19,558.14c-.32-2.18-.77-4.36-.89-6.56a3.15,3.15,0,0,1,1.31-2.05,1.76,1.76,0,0,1,1.64.49,4.19,4.19,0,0,1,.17,2.5c-.48,1.84-1.18,3.62-1.79,5.43Z" transform="translate(-0.06 -0.26)" />
      <path class="cls-1" d="M40.77,527.77l-7-8.41.35-.18A76,76,0,0,1,40.4,524c.77.71.87,2.14,1.27,3.25Z" transform="translate(-0.06 -0.26)" />
      <path class="cls-1" d="M493.56,95.47l3.41,6L485.7,105a30.91,30.91,0,0,1,2.81-2.42C491.7,100.51,493.64,100.2,493.56,95.47Z" transform="translate(-0.06 -0.26)" />
    </g>
    <g id="Yukon" data-name="Yukon">
      <path class="cls-3" d="M174.12,185.61c.91,1.61.88,2.8-.63,4.31-4.21,4.21-8.16,8.68-12.2,13.07-.34.38-.78,1-.72,1.39.58,3.9-2,6.08-4.31,8.53a6.48,6.48,0,0,0-1.84,3.83,5.33,5.33,0,0,0,1.79,3.5c1.85,1.68,4.07,2.94,6,4.53,3.45,2.83,3.47,5.7.33,9.15-2.19,2.39-4.41,4.77-6.37,7.34-1.76,2.3-1.12,4.05,1.42,5.49,1.4.81,2.66,1.88,4.19,3-2.18,1.51-3.35,2.81-2.33,5.22.45,1.05,0,2.31-1.73,2.4a17.09,17.09,0,0,0-3.62.83c-4.36,1.21-5.4,4.72-5.53,8.56a57.14,57.14,0,0,0,.5,10c.23,1.57,1.5,3,2.39,4.63-2.26,2.84-2.38,6.32-1.6,10.12a46.41,46.41,0,0,1,.52,7.56,1.6,1.6,0,0,1-.82,1.17c-2.55,1.24-3,3.61-3.48,6a9.38,9.38,0,0,1-1.27,3.48,10.68,10.68,0,0,0-1.7,8.87,2.39,2.39,0,0,1-.44,1.48c-.6,1-1.32,2-2,2.93-1.42,2.18-1.43,4,.77,5.24,3.32,1.83,3.1,4.7,2.57,7.41-.72,3.66-.45,6.87,2,9.78,1.47,1.77,1.39,3.3-.37,4.95a7.72,7.72,0,0,0-1.45,3.08c-.28.81-.27,1.71-.5,2.53-1.52,5.43,1,6.26,4.74,7.61,1.41.5,2.57,1.66,3.93,2.34a26.86,26.86,0,0,0,4.63,1.87c1.72.5,3.51.73,5.24,1.06.05.25.15.5.1.53-3,2.14-3,5.28-2.81,8.48.09,2,0,4,0,6.25A575.11,575.11,0,0,1,48.14,298a7.87,7.87,0,0,1,.58-.75c3.2-3.33,3.13-5.09-.71-7.55a38.29,38.29,0,0,0-6.52-3.12c-2.14-.86-3.05-5-1.32-6.73q13.23-13,26.49-26c6.81-6.67,13.65-13.31,20.46-20q13.26-13,26.5-26,10.56-10.35,21.15-20.68,11.07-10.83,22.16-21.66c1.92-1.87,3.87-3.74,6-5.43a2.44,2.44,0,0,1,2.34-.08,12.63,12.63,0,0,1,4.51,7.68c.95,5.52,2.44,10.95,3.73,16.42A5.64,5.64,0,0,0,174.12,185.61Z" transform="translate(-0.06 -0.26)" />
    </g>
    <g id="British_Columiba" data-name="British Columiba">
      <g>
        <path class="cls-4" d="M190.26,405.28c.27.14.53.31,1.06.62-1,1.88-2,3.69-2.9,5.53-5.64,11.14-11.24,22.3-16.9,33.43-4.43,8.73-8.92,17.42-13.38,26.13l-19.37,37.93c-.21.42-.68.84-.65,1.24.17,2.7,0,5.24-2.52,6.95.78,2,1.25,4.14,2.45,5.8.82,1.15,1.83,1.89,1.89,3.54s.46,3.46,2.33,4.55c2.39,1.41,1.92,4.19,2.3,6.41.31,1.81-.17,3.77-.35,5.66s.8,3.35,2.22,4.62a2.72,2.72,0,0,1,.81,2.17,5.54,5.54,0,0,0,1.49,5.42c.88,1,1.18,2.44,1.69,3.71.82,2,1.6,4,2.38,6,1,2.51,2,5,2.9,7.55.32.88.14,2.18.72,2.67,3.23,2.74,2.75,6.63,3,10.1a15.41,15.41,0,0,0,3.74,8.9c3.16,3.57,2.61,7,1.68,10.73-.83,3.31-1.92,6.57-3,9.84s-.35,6.2,1.21,9.74c-5.31-2.27-10.13-4.28-14.9-6.38-10.53-4.64-21.08-9.23-31.54-14-8.14-3.72-16.25-7.52-24.19-11.65-8.81-4.6-17.41-9.61-26.09-14.47a2,2,0,0,1-1-1.12,65.21,65.21,0,0,1-1-7.47c-.16-3.6-1.05-5-4.37-5.94,0-1.19,0-2.34,0-3.5a3.82,3.82,0,0,0-2.71-3.76c-1.17-.5-3.27-.93-3.32-1.53a9.88,9.88,0,0,1,.91-5.44c3.08-5.49,3.08-7.06-1-11.44-2.29-2.47-4.78-4.79-6.82-7.46a9.16,9.16,0,0,1-1.44-4.76c-.2-2.61-1.08-4.69-3.49-5.72-3.27-1.39-4.67-4.2-5.48-7.23a5.27,5.27,0,0,1,1-4.36,5.48,5.48,0,0,0,1.59-5.2c-.48-3.26,1.93-4.89,4.78-5.55a19.58,19.58,0,0,0,3.83-1c2.43-1.12,2.65-3.06.7-4.87a7.78,7.78,0,0,1-2-9.22c1.46-3.4,1.33-5.05-1-6.15-1.19-.56-2.78-.29-4.19-.39-.47,0-.93-.05-1.65-.09,1.67-3,3-5.78,6.86-6.28a4.12,4.12,0,0,0,3.2-2.73c.72-1.68,2.44-2.95,3.74-4.38,1.14-1.23,1.82-2.81.52-4a5.8,5.8,0,0,0-4-1A30.06,30.06,0,0,0,44.62,459c-1.84-6.08-.47-11.9,1.17-17.65A3.74,3.74,0,0,1,48,439.05c7.2-1.55,10.53-7,13.68-12.85a30.35,30.35,0,0,1,3.83-4.91c1.69-2,2.72-4.14,1.8-6.84s-1.71-5.51-2.66-8.23A52.51,52.51,0,0,0,62,399.51c-1.34-2.62-.9-5.19-.39-7.83q2.15-11.08,4.26-22.15c1.08-5.61,2.21-11.21,3.21-16.84a9.48,9.48,0,0,0-.36-2.74c-.16-1.32-.33-2.65-.44-4-.14-1.58-.18-3.17-.36-4.74a11.92,11.92,0,0,1,1.16-7.34c1.92-3.53,1.66-7.9-.48-9.87l1.06-1.21c7.65,6.68,15.29,13.38,23.2,19.74,8.69,7,17.59,13.76,26.79,20,13.27,9,26.71,17.88,40.42,26.24C169.85,394.8,180.18,399.83,190.26,405.28Z" transform="translate(-0.06 -0.26)" />
        <path class="cls-4" d="M67.71,323.4c-4.2-2.13-8.84-4.21-13.43-1.55-2.84,1.64-5.18.87-8.06.13,2.21-2.52,1.9-5.53,1.88-8.49s0-6.08,0-9.44a8.14,8.14,0,0,1,1.68.85c5.42,4.9,10.73,9.92,16.24,14.72l3.65,3.2L68.61,324A4,4,0,0,0,67.71,323.4Z" transform="translate(-0.06 -0.26)" />
        <path class="cls-1" d="M52.34,580.17c.15,1.23-.68,2.57-1.25,4.47-2.23-1.77-4.17-2.89-5.53-4.5a75.63,75.63,0,0,1-5.85-8.23,3.32,3.32,0,0,1-.2-2.75c2.52-5.09,2.08-6.95-3.06-9.61-1.82-.94-2.5-1.94-2.32-4,.32-3.52.35-4.15-4.79-9.94,2-2.92,1.55-3.82-.24-7-1.32-2.35-1.69-5.31-2.07-8.06-.29-2.13-.63-4-2.58-5.25a2.26,2.26,0,0,1-.79-1.75c.24-3.45.6-6.89.93-10.33,2-.08,2.8,1.11,3.33,2.71A29.72,29.72,0,0,0,36,529,45.65,45.65,0,0,1,43,536.54c1.16,1.66,1.53,4.06,1.7,6.17a84.4,84.4,0,0,1,0,10.06c-.17,4.12,1.42,7.63,3.38,11.07a18,18,0,0,1,2.24,4.56A109.17,109.17,0,0,1,52.34,580.17Z" transform="translate(-0.06 -0.26)" />
        <path class="cls-1" d="M17.57,426.81l6.17,8.48C16.39,441.78,11.81,449.73,11,459.7,10.41,448.18,12.87,437.39,17.57,426.81Z" transform="translate(-0.06 -0.26)" />
      </g>
    </g>
    <g id="Alberta" data-name="Alberta">
      <path class="cls-5" d="M194.56,407.63c27.17,14.46,55.83,25.35,85,35.57L214.1,643.67c-10.88-4-21.29-7.82-31.68-11.68-3.52-1.3-6.91-3-10.51-4s-5.08-3.41-6.18-6.74c-1.26-3.84-.43-7.18,1.12-10.59A26.88,26.88,0,0,0,169.13,597a4.52,4.52,0,0,0-1-2.58c-4.16-4.42-5.32-9.88-5.71-15.66-.07-1-.13-2.32-.75-2.88-2.84-2.56-2.45-6.26-3.65-9.38-.64-1.69-1.62-3.26-2.29-4.95-.84-2.14-1.52-4.35-2.27-6.53-.05-.15-.06-.35-.17-.44a6.25,6.25,0,0,1-2-7.07c.17-.6-1.07-1.75-1.85-2.43a2.33,2.33,0,0,1-1.08-2.43,28.92,28.92,0,0,0-.52-7.52c-.36-2.17,0-4.65-2.15-6.28-1.47-1.09-1.92-2.71-2.35-4.49-.35-1.45-1.6-2.69-2.47-4-.51-.77-1.07-1.51-1.72-2.42,2.55-1.41,2.87-3.59,2.69-6a5,5,0,0,1,.5-2.5q5-9.88,10-19.7c6.78-13.11,13.63-26.19,20.37-39.32,3.84-7.45,7.51-15,11.31-22.47C187.5,421.2,191,414.48,194.56,407.63Z" transform="translate(-0.06 -0.26)" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Here's how the full map looks: https://jsfiddle.net/darkosss/7umphzwn/

Comment: I really like that! Thank you for this!